# Is my logic correct? Ajax and/or PHP with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a page which shows a list of items. Page coded with html, css, php and using mysql db.

On that page a user can request to add one of the items to their special list.

I want to do this within the page without having to do a complete page refresh. So user clicks button to add, item is added to their list and button changed so they can't add it again.

Do I use ajax calls to run code behind the page and then refresh the div?

Or is there a better more efficient way to do it.

I'd prefer a php option of possible in case user has js turned off, but don't know if it can be done with using js.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: in short, yes, you are correct. there is no php only way that wont refresh the whole page, check they have js on or warn them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want dynamic content (changing the page without refreshing) you are going to have to use Javascript. To do what you are asking, you could call a PHP script via Ajax that outputs the contents of the div with the new item, and then change the div based on that response.

Answer (score 0):

Dagon is exactly right. Create a form which handles the request and set the action of the form to the PHP script you want to handle the request. Note that although this can be the same php script that you use to process your ajax request, it does not necessarily have to be.

Many times when I implement such functionality, I'll set the PHP to send variables as POST (in the event of JS disabled) and have my ajax request as a GET so I can use a single PHP page to handle the 'same' request. When using AJAX, I'll have the script echo a specific code then have the ajax response handle that return.

```
if(val == 'OK') {
 //in event of success, perhaps you want to hide the original form and show a success message
} else {
  //do something like unhide a hidden div to display an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If JavaScript is turned off, the page has to be reloaded. In your case [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) could be  very handy and simply rewrite the element you need to rewrite. The server send's a simple json. Using a PHP Framework might also be a good idea, since the way you ask it seems (with respect, and not wanting to offend), that you are not using any framework and might run into falls making your script vulnerable (sql injections for example)

If your visitor doesn't have JavaScript enabled and you want to serve anyways, then you have to do a page reload. First check if that is worth to do, who is your client/visitor, what browser do they use, ... questions like that help you to design your page/app.